# How to implement a Low-Level LL_GPIO_ReadPin( function in STM32f103

Tags: stm32, gpio, low-level

Using CubeMX and CubeMxIDE an example for reading a button if using HAL drivers works.
https://karedox.com/?p=193 .

However, I need to read a GPIO pin using low-level drivers.
But apparently, LL_GPIO_ReadPin(SW_GPIO_Port, SW_Pin)
is not implemented

whereas

LL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin) does not give an error.

Is there a low-level driver solution for GPIO_ReadPin?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend

```
LL_GPIO_IsInputPinSet(SW_GPIO_Port, SW_Pin)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

why just not:

`!!(SW_GPIO_Port -> IDR & (1 << SW_PIN))`

Comment: Thank you.
I am still being on a very very flat learning curve with respect to the STM32s.
Could you explain briefly what "!!" and "->" will be doing?

Comment: it is not stm32 it is just `C` language. If you do not know what `->` is  you need to start from the book

Comment: Yes I know that. But unlike many others, STM32 is relying heavily on C et al. But dou you believe that meaning of "!!" isn't found by G.....? And the pointer neither. Try searching for "C".... So I am being still left in the dark. Thank you.